# Selecteddatakey always null asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, null

I using a gridview that is populated on a rowcommand event of an another data gridview

the problem is when ever I try to use the selecteddatakey property on a selectedchanged event its always gives me the error

> object refrence not set to an instance of an object

```
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busid", GridView2.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
```

I run with debugging and found that the selecteddatakey was null

heres the code I used to populate the gridview

```
SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCA Database;Integrated Security=True";
                SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "FindAvaliableBuses";
                SqlDataSource2.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
                SqlDataSource2.DataBind();

                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                string Startdate = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
                string DueDate = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
                SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("startdate", Startdate);
                SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("duedate", DueDate);
                SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters.Add("branchId", "11");
                GridView2.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
                GridView2.DataBind();
                GridView2.DataKeyNames = new string[] {"BusId"};
                Label1.Text = index.ToString();
```

and here's the code I use for selection:

```
protected void GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WCA Database;Integrated Security=True");
    con1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert BusAcivity (BusId, ActivityId) values(@busid, @activityid)", con1);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@busid", GridView2.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@activityid", Label1.Text);
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: _Hmm_, did you set [`DataKeyNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) property?

Comment: Try with `SelectedIndexChanged` event instead..